# How to setup VS2013 Preview to work with v120 toolset?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

When I set project toolset to v120 I'm getting:

> error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed or
> invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is
> selected.
>
> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets   511

So where should I get it? How to install it? So far I can't find any solution.

Comment: Ignore that, v120 is the toolset version number for VS2013.  Well, the install didn't go well.  Not that unlikely, the installer is always the very last thing they get solid before the RTM version ships.  You can spin the wheel of fortune and try to reinstall but that's not terribly likely to come to a good end.  Try another machine, a clean VM is always a good idea when you install preview editions of VS.

Comment: Preview gives ~200 days for development before release so I want to have it on my machine. I will be happy if some fix will come or maybe someone will discover some trick to repair it.